# Changing link colors doesnt work in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I have this JavaScript code that sets a background color to the latest pressed link:

```
<script>
function changeClass(Index) {
    var ids = new Array(
        "null", "homenav", "coffeenav", "sidenav", "standnav",
        "dinnernav", "stoolsnav", "pedestalsnav",
        "galleriesnav", "pressnav", "factsnav", "contactnav"
    );
    var color = new Array(
        "null", "#c9a900", "#f32837", "#0085cf",
        "#00aa86", "#c99900", "c42695", "#617f90",
        "#4814a9","#71a28a","#ac27a9","#998f86"
    );
    var i = 1;
    var length = ids.length;
    while (i < length) {
        document.getElementById(ids[i]).style.backgroundColor = '#FFF';
        document.getElementById(ids[i]).setAttribute("class","blacklink");
        document.getElementById(ids[Index]).style.backgroundColor =color[Index];
        document.getElementById(ids[Index]).setAttribute("class","whitelink");
        i++;
    }
}
</script>
```

And I also have a table that looks like this:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" class="menyrad">
 <tr valign="middle" align="center">
  <td width="10%" id="homenav">
    <a href="framsida_test.html" onClick="changeClass(1)">Furniture home</a>
 </td>
 <td width="10%" id="coffeenav">
  <a href="coffee.html" onClick="changeClass(2)">Coffee tables</a>
 </td>
 <td width="9%" id="sidenav">
  <a href="side.html" onClick="changeClass(3)">Side tables</a>
 </td>
 <td width="9%" id="standnav">
  <a href="stand.html" onClick="changeClass(4)">Stand tables</a>
 </td>
 <td width="8%" id="dinnernav">
  <a href="dinner.html" onClick="changeClass(5)">Dinner tables</a>
 </td>
 <td width="6%" id="stoolsnav">
  <a href="stools.html" onClick="changeClass(6)">Stools</a>
 </td>
 <td width="8%" id="pedestalsnav">
  <a href="pedestals.html" onClick="changeClass(7)">Pedestals</a>
 </td>
 <td width="8%" id="galleriesnav">
  <a href="galleries.html" onClick="changeClass(8)">Galleries</a>
 </td>
 <td width="6%" id="pressnav">
  <a href="press.html" onClick="changeClass(9)">Press</a>
 </td>
 <td width="6%" id="factsnav">
  <a href="facts.html" onClick="changeClass(10)">Facts</a>
 </td>
 <td width="8%" id="contactnav">
  <a href="contact.php" onClick="changeClass(11)">Contact</a>
 </td>
```

The CSS for `class="menyrad"`, `class="whitelink"` and `class ="blacklink"` looks like this:

```
.menyrad td {
  font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size:10px;
}

.whitelink {
  color:#fff;
  outline:0;
  font-weight:bold;
}

.blacklink a {
  color:#000;
  outline:0;
}
```

This works fine in all browsers BUT Internet Explorer (I checked with IE9, doesn't seem to work in any version though). When I press any link the link gets a block of color around it, the text changes to bold white and there is no dotted outline around the pressed link. In IE the colored block shows up, but the text is black and not bold, and there is an outline.

What can I do?

Comment: In the loop, there's a variable named `Index`? Where's that coming from?

Comment: @Whymarrh The Index variable comes from the pressed link. The first link has the onclick event set to changeCLass(1), the second changeClass(2) and so on. It determines what link has been pressed every time the loop runs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Old versions of Internet Explorer (and modern versions when they are in Quirks/Compatibility modes) have a broken implementation of `setAttribute`. Don't use it. Set the associated DOM property instead.

```
element.className = "foo";
```

Comment: Im not familiar with this, how would it look in the code for this instance?
document.getElementById(ids[Index]).element.className = "whitelink";?

Comment: `document.getElementById(ids[Index]).className = "whitelink";`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following CSS:

```
.blacklink a,
.blacklink a:link,
.blacklink a:visited
{
    color:#000;
    outline:0;
}
```

Comment: Sadly didn't help, I have the same problem where the pressed link is black and not bold. Is it something wrong with my whilelink class?